# django admin navigation from model to model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

got 4 tables:

1. `main`.
2. got a foreign key to `A`.
3. got a foreign key to `B`.
4. got a foreign key to `C`.

I've setup models and can see and edit them after registering in Admin, but all they go their own way. What should I do to access model 2. by selecting is reference in model 1. changelist ?

```
main information > click on it > access model B) data`
```

Or, can I do it outside the admin with two separate Listviews ?

Comment: Do you want to access the data for model 2 while still on the page for model 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe **Inline Formsets** is what you are looking for.
Look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) for info and example.